# Positioning at width 100%

Tags: css, positioning

I cannot work out why the div class pic-container won't align to the top of the page with the other 3.

Each of the child divs have a width of 25%.

I have a feeling I've missed something obvious..

Example here:
http://tinkerbin.com/NS7vagaq

Comment: Ignoring whitespace with `font-size: 0;` is not good.

Comment: Could you kindly explain why?

Comment: @bengem That's not a good practise.

Comment: Sorry to be pedantic (trying to learn as much as possible) Why is it bad practise? What are the alternatives?

Comment: @bengem: It doesn’t work in IE7 and 8, if I recall correctly, and can introduce a few other strange problems. I’ll find the Stack Overflow question at some point! :D Anyways, the alternative is to just not put whitespace between them, unfortunately. It may not look as nice, but it’s much more reliable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set

```
.pic-container{
    font-size:0;
    }
```

to `display: inline;`

So it is:

```
.pic-container{
    font-size:0;
    display:inline;
    }
```

---

Since you have changed the structure of your code so the above no longer works try this instead:

```
<div class="pic_container">
    <img src="images/1.jpg">  
    <span class="viewer">  
        <img src="images/2.jpg">
        <img src="images/3.jpg">
    </span>
    <img src="images/4.jpg">
</div>
```

No special CSS needed.

Comment: I've made the changes to my local version but still having issues: [Local changes here](http://tinkerbin.com/zTIMqXlg)

Comment: Well you changed the structure of the code so of course it's not working. Why do you now have two separate divs of class pic_container and then nest another div inside the first of those? What, exactly, are you trying to achieve? 4 images across? 4 images across with the middle two inside some sort of container?

Comment: I tried adjusting it and failed. Yes, 4 images across with 2 in the middle in a container (will be a slider once i've figured it out)

Comment: What, exactly, are you trying to achieve? 4 images across? 4 images across with the middle two inside some sort of container?

Comment: Yes, 4 images across with 2 in the middle in a container (will be a slider once i've figured it out)

Comment: See my above edit. It uses an inline level element `<span>` to contain the interior images.

Comment: Thanks. Although this doesn't seem to worth with width 100%?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "doesn't seem to worth with width 100%". But if you place the whole thing inside a container with a width of 100% it will work fine.

Comment: Thank you for your patience.. I've got a lot to learn..! This is what I was meaning: [link](http://tinkerbin.com/GaV8PCZg) Sorry - typo on my part!! Thank you so much for your help

Comment: You are getting some extra width or padding or margins from somewhere so each image takes up 25% of the space then the extra width pushes things beyond the available space and causes it to wrap. Set the images to take up 24.9% and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you have the fourth identicon in a DIV separate from the other three. Since DIVs are block-level elements, the identicon in the second "pic-container" div will appear below the others.

If you move the fourth identicon also into the same div container as the first three, they line up.

Answer (score 0):

Because divs are block level elements. Change it to inline and voila.

```
div {
  display:inline;
}
```

http://tinkerbin.com/rz9WlaIg

Answer (score 0):

Change the CSS to:

```
.pic-container{
    font-size:0;
    display: inline;
}
```

#### Fiddle: http://tinkerbin.com/DH6nLkQO

Answer (score 0):

You could also float it.

```
.pic-container img { margin:0; padding: 0; float:left; }
```